# logging error in python

Tags: python, logging, operating-system

I have been writing simple scripts and I am trying to use logger to generate log for each functions in the scripts.

1) based on the function name I create a logger filehandler and I try to put logs using that handler. I also delete the previous existing file with the same name.

3) at the end of the function I close the handler.

My problem are:

1)even though I close the handler, the next time I run the same function I get an error that the file I am trying to delete is (as a part of setting the logger file handler) is still being used.

2) Also the logger prints everything to console which I dont want, I just want it to write everything to the file.

Here are the logger functions:

```
def setLogger(path):

"""
@purpose: Intializes basic logging directory and file
"""
LOG_FILENAME = path + "\\" + "log.txt"
#logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
#                format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.INFO
#                )
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s")
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
return logger


def unsetLogger(logger):

"""
@purpose: performs a basic shutdown of logger
"""

logger.handlers[0].close()
logger.removeHandler(logger.handlers[0])
logging.shutdown
```

The way i use them is:
for eg:

```
def fun():
        os.remove(path)
        logger = setLogger(path)
`       logging.info("hi") #this writes to file and prints on the console as well
        unsetLogger(logger)
```

if I run the function fun() once, its all good. but if i run it again, I get that can't delete error for the log file.

Thanks in Advance.
learningNinja

Comment: Why are you deleting the file every time you run the method again? Do you really not want more than one execution in the log at a time? Why not append to the existing file (which is the default), and use something like a TimedRotatingFileHandler which would help prevent the file from getting too big?

Comment: Actually I did it as per requirement. I can't append the files else would have done.

Answer (score 0):

After making some slight modifications, I came up with the following test to try to reproduce your error, but I don't get any errors.

```
import os
import logging

def setLogger(path):
    """
    @purpose: Intializes basic logging directory and file
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # Simplified log file path (I just use full value passed in, and don't append "\log.txt")
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(path)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s")
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger

def unsetLogger(logger):
    """
    @purpose: performs a basic shutdown of logger
    """
    logger.handlers[0].close()
    logger.removeHandler(logger.handlers[0])
    logging.shutdown

def fun():
    try:
        # Was getting error trying to remove a file that didn't exist on
        # first execution...
        os.remove("log.txt")
    except:
        pass
    logger = setLogger("log.txt")
    logging.info("hi")
    unsetLogger(logger)

fun()
fun()
fun()
```

See if there is anything I'm doing differently than your actual code and maybe that might help you.

Comment: It didn't even log on you console? I know its weird even It was working for me and I don't remember what different I did today and all this started to happen. I have been trying since morning and no matter what I do, i keep getting those errors not always but intermittently. Even I tried to put my delete log file code in try block. but then if it fails to delete, it appends.

Comment: I put the full contents of what I posted above into a file called "testlog.py" and ran it and I didn't see any output to the console. It created the log file and at the end of execution, only one line was logged, as expected. I even debugged and stepped through each call to `fun()`, and it created and deleted the log file each time as expected.

Comment: Oh, and also, I didn't see any logging being printed to the console as your code comment indicates that you saw. There is not a `StreamHandler` being added to the logger in the code above, so that shouldn't happen. Do you have some code somewhere else that is adding a `StreamHandler`? That might be your issue, because then `logger.handlers[0]` might not be the `FileHandler`. Try adding a unique logger name to your `logging.getLogger()` call (e.g., `logging.getLogger("mylogger")`) and see if that helps at all. It should at least remove the console output.